# Objective-C/Swift (iOS) When are the auto-constraints applied in the View/ViewController work flow?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, constraints, awakefromnib

I'm having some issues of figuring out when the `auto-contraints` setup on a `XIB` are applied in the view setup process.

For more explanation:

- I've setup a `XIB` for a view
- I set the "Simulated Metrics" Size to iPhone 3.5-Inch
- I've added auto-constraints to the subviews inside this view
- In the View Controller I perform certain operations dependent on the subview (`IBOutlet`) `frames/bounds` in the `viewDidLoad` method
- In the View I perform certain operations dependent on the subview (`IBOutlet`) `frames/bounds` in the `awakeFromNib` method

In those 2 methods (`ViewController::viewDidLoad and View::awakeFromNib`) the IBOutlet views HAVE been loaded but the constraints have no yet been applied. The actual frame is still set to the iPhone 3.5" size (width 320) when using a larger simulator (such as the iPhone 6 simulator).

When are these auto-constraints applied and when should any necessary operations that would need the ACTUAL frame/bounds of the subviews take place?

I'm using XCode 6.3, Swift (1.2)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The constraints are applied in the `layoutSubviews` method. So if you want to do something after they are applied in a `UIView` subclass, override the method:

```
   override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    //the frames have now their final values, after applying constraints
  }
```

In a `UIViewController` subclass, use `viewDidLayoutSubviews` for the same purpose:

```
  override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
    //the frames have now their final values, after applying constraints
  }
```

Please note that you shouldn't set `frame` / `bounds` for a view if you added auto layout constraints to this view.

Comment: While working with a custom UITableViewCell subclass, this alone didn't update the frames immediately; only scrolling away from a cell and again caused it to be laid out. Adding `setNeedsLayout(); layoutIfNeeded` at the end of my `updateConstraints` override seems to have fixed it. Surprisingly, replacing `layoutIfNeeded` with `layout` did not work, not even after `setNeedsLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Note for Xcode 8:
If you use auto layout, you may have a problem with new feature: *view as [any device]*. When you test your app on another device(simulator) and have *inferred* screen, screen bounds for this device gonna be applied in *viewWillLayoutSubviews*.

Answer (score 0):

you can use method

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
super.layoutSubviews()
//the frames have now their final values, after applying constraints
```

}

But this method will be called multiple times in a view's life cycle, such as orientation change or moving in and out views, so you need to handle this.